# The difference between 文書 and 文書化

Tags: word-choice

I wonder what is the difference between the words **文書{ぶんしょ}** and **文書化{ぶんしょか}**. Both of them have meaning of ***"documentation"*** or ***"documents"***, but I am not capable to distinguish them. Could you please share your ideas? Thank you a lot in advance!

Answer (score 5):

文書 is a noun. The meaning is 'a document'.

文書化 is a verb. The meaning is 'documenting'. So it means 'To record in documents'. If a noun attached `化`, it almost mean 'making (something) (a noun)'. In this pattern, 'making (something) a document'.

Example:

> - この文書は説得力がなさそうだ。
>
>   - This document looks to make no sense.
> - そうだ、これを文書化しよう。
>
>   - Oh yeah. Let's document this.

Related: [http://www.weblio.jp/content/文書化](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E6%96%87%E6%9B%B8%E5%8C%96)